# Laravel 5.2 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::activateTask()

Tags: php, laravel

I am a newbie using laravel and got into a problem after I changed my code from routes to controller.

All the code was working perfect while I had them placed in routes.php, but when I made this code into a function in controller Task.php and added the function function to routes.php I got the following error ->

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2161: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::activateTask()



in Builder.php line 2161
at Builder->__call('activateTask', array(object(Task)))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'activateTask'), array(object(Task))) in Builder.php line 1313
at Builder->__call('activateTask', array(object(Task)))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'activateTask'), array(object(Task))) in Model.php line 3490
at Model->__call('activateTask', array(object(Task)))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Task), 'activateTask'), array(object(Task))) in Model.php line 3504
at Model::__callStatic('activateTask', array(object(Task))) in routes.php line 45
at RouteServiceProvider->{closure}(object(Task))
at call_user_func_array(object(Closure), array('task' => object(Task))) in Route.php line 158
at Route->runCallable(object(Request)) in Route.php line 137
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('D:\wamp64\organizer\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

My task controller Task.php ->

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class Task extends Controller
{
    //

    public function activateTask($task)
    {
        if($task->active == 1)
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }
        else
        {
            $task->active = 1;
            $task->save();
            if(Session('active') != null)
            {
                $oldtask = App\Session::find(Session('active'));
                $oldtask->Task->active = 0;
                $oldtask->Task->save();
                $oldtask->touch();
                $oldtask->save();
            }
            $session = new Session;
            $session->task()->associate($task);
            $session->save();
            Session(['active' => $session->id]);
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }

    public function saveTask($request) {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('/')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }

        $task = new Task;
        $task->name = $request->name;
        $task->deadline = $request->deadline;
        $task->save();
    }

}
```

Tasks model Task.php ->

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    //
    public function sessions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Session');
    }
}
```

Sessions model Session.php ->

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Session extends Model
{
    //

    public function task()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Task');
    }

}
```

routes.php ->

```
<?php

use App\Task;
use App\Session;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //

    Route::get('/', function() {
        $task = Task::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        return view('layouts/tasks', [
            'tasks' => $task
        ]);

    });


    Route::post('/task', function (Request $request) {
        Task::saveTask($request);
    /*   
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('/')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }

        $task = new Task;
        $task->name = $request->name;
        $task->deadline = $request->deadline;
        $task->save();


    */
        return redirect('/');
    });



    Route::post('/task/{task}/activate', function (Task $task) {
        Task::activateTask($task);
    });



    Route::post('/task/{task}/deactivate', function (Task $task) {
        $task->active = 0;
        $task->save();
        $session = App\Session::find(Session('active'));
        $session->touch();

        $started = strtotime($session->created_at);
        $ended = strtotime($session->updated_at);
        $hours = abs(($ended - $started))/(60*60);
        $session->hours = $hours;

        $session->save();
        Session(['active' => null]);
        return redirect('/');

    });

    Route::delete('/task/{task}', function (Task $task){
        if($session = Session::find(Session('active')))
        {
            if($session->task->id == $task->id)
            {
                Session(['active', null]);
            }
        }

        $task->delete();
        return redirect('/');
    });

});
```

Problem happens when I press button to post to the routes.

Tried to google the problem and tried different approaches to fix this but no luck at all. I am pretty sure it is something really easy and dumb but cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your routes are not setup correctly. To use controllers, you pass a string as the second parameter in a `controller@method` format. So, your route should look like this:

```
Route::post('/task/{task}/activate', 'Task@activateTask');
```

Also, your controller method is expecting the value passed in to be the model, not an id, so you'll want to type hint your parameter to take advantage of implicit model binding:

```
public function activateTask(\App\Task $task) {
    //
}
```

You may want to take a look at the [routing documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying to find out from the documentation. I just did not understand how the variable is passed through the route.. but it seems that it does it automatically if you request it in the function?

That started working after addin use App/Session to Task controller. Got some more problems but hopefully can swim thorough them on my own.